# Is it possible to construct non-analytic functions on the real line in constructive analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, constructive-mathematics

I'm just a curious outsider when it comes to constructive mathematics, but it seems to me that it is not possible to actually construct non-analytic functions. It seems that the classical counterexamples of step functions, absolute value function, and bump functions cannot be defined constructively. Am I correct or is it possible to actually exhibit a non-analytic function?

I would prefer *not* to assume any choice principles (dependent choice, countable choice etc.).

Comment: I'd think the absolute value function, as well as the classic $\begin{cases} e^{-1/x}, & x > 0 \\ 0, & x \le 0 \end{cases}$, should be computable.  Sure, you can't compute whether $x > 0$ or not in general, but in both cases after you know $x$ is close enough to 0 you can just return 0 as the approximation to $f(x)$.  A step function certainly wouldn't be computable, though.

Comment: That definition no longer gives a function on the entire real line, because we cannot assume that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \leq 0$ or $x>0$.

Comment: Well, that was what I was hinting at how to get around in the comment.  So for example, if $\frac{m}{2^n}$ is a "good" dyadic rational approximation to $x$ returned by the construction of $x$, then $\frac{|m|}{2^n}$ is a good dyadic rational approximation to $|x|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The absolute value function can certainly be defined for the Cauchy real line or Dedekind real line.

For the Cauchy real line, it's easy: given a sequence $x_n$ send it to $|x_n|.$ This is a well-defined map of Cauchy sequences.

For the Dedekind real line, the lower bounds are any rational $r$ such that $r<x$ or $r<-x,$ and the upper bounds are any rational $r$ such that $x<r$ and $-x<r.$ To show this defines a Dedekind cut we should show it is "located", i.e. for any rationals $a<b,$ either $a$ is a lower bound or $b$ is an upper bound (a sort of limited excluded middle). The interesting case is when $0<a<b.$ Since $x$ is located we know that either $a<x$ or $x<b,$ but also that either $-b<x$ or $x<-a.$ Either of $a<x$ or $x<-a$ imply $a<|x|,$ and in the other cases we have $|x|<b.$

This covers constructive analysis as pioneered by Bishop.

---

Similarly $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\leq 0\\e^{-1/x}&x>0\end{cases}$ can be defined constructively i.e. there is a constructive definition which is classically equivalent to the classical definition. I'll just work with Dedekind cuts.

A rational $r$ is a lower bound of $f(x)$ if $r<0$ or if $r<e^{-1/a}$ for some positive rational $a<x.$ A rational $r$ is an upper bound of $f(x)$ if $r>e^{-1/b}$ for some positive rational $b>x.$

To show $f(x)$ is located, consider a rational interval $a<b.$ If $a<0$ then $a<f(x).$ Otherwise, by continuity of $\exp$ there are rationals $0<a'<b'$ with $a<e^{-1/a'}<e^{-1/b'}<b.$ That's just a statement about rationals so there aren't any constructive subtleties. Since $x$ is located, either $x<b'$ or $a'<x.$ If $x<b'$ then $f(x)<b.$ If $a'<x$ then $a<f(x).$ In all cases we have shown $a<f(x)$ or $f(x)<b$ as required.

A more general construction is that a function on $\mathbb Q$ that is uniformly continuous on bounded sets extends to $\mathbb R.$ The proof is just the usual proof for a metric space completion, though with a bit more care if trying to avoid countable choice.

Comment: Thanks! So we still have a constructive example of a non-smooth function. Are there constructive examples of non-analytic smooth functions? I don't see how we can constructively define bump functions.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ: Yes. You can construct a function $f$ as long as you can constructively approximate $f(x)$ given an approximation to $x.$ This means the usual constructions go through without any trouble. (This is just me agreeing with Daniel Schepler's comments.)

Comment: Sorry if I'm being thick, but I still just can't grasp how to define the bump function constructively. Given a real number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ given by a Dedekind cut $(L_x, R_x)$, how do we assign a value to it in such a way that we get the bump function? Certainly if we can decide $x \leq 0$ or $x >0$ then we can use the standard piecewise formula, but what if we lack evidence for either?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ: I've added a section saying how you could define a bump in terms of Dedekind cuts

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write up a detailed explanation!

Comment: Does this mean the derivative of the absolute value function simply doesn't exist? Or is there a way to handle that.

Comment: @PyRulez It is differentiable on $U = (-\infty, 0)\cup(0,\infty)$, and we can constructively define its derivative on $U$. It's just like in classical mathematics. Note that this provides a *continuous* function on $U$, so nothing is wrong.